# Insert and retrieve image from db using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i am new in ROR. 
I am trying to insert image in db but could not find proper solution. 
Kindly tell me the best way for it. I doesn't want to use paperclip gem.

Comment: why don't you want to use paperclip, do you want to write your own solution?

Comment: ok, if you don't want to use paperclip, use carrierwave

Comment: i don't have to much images. just 2 and 3 images that are not more then 35kb. that's why i want to use db